# Uncorrelating correlated $\chi^2$ distribution

Tags: distributions, correlation, simulation, chi-squared-distribution, cholesky-decomposition

This question is related to my previous question in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154175/simulate-correlated-chi2-distribution)

So I was trying to simulate correlated $\chi^2(1)$ random variables given the desired co-variance matrix. However, it seems like the only possible route was the following

Given the co-variance matrix $R$, then we perform the cholesky decomposition such that
$$
R=LL^t
$$
Then we simulate a number of independent vector $A$ with $N\sim(0,1)$, we can then simulate $B$ using
$$
LA=B
$$
where B should be correlated $N\sim(0,1)$, then we can obtain the correlated $\chi^2(1)$ variables.

When playing around with the variables, I thought that given
$$
LA=B
$$
and that the correlated $\chi^2$ are simply $B^2$, then by squaring the equation, I should be able to get the corresponding independent $\chi^2$ variables e.g.
$$
LAA^tL^t=BB^t
$$
However, I note that $AA^t$ and $BB^t$ are both square matrix, so I am not sure whether if they are both $\chi^2$ distributed. What interested me most is that: given a set of correlated random variables that are normally distributed, we can simply use the cholesky distribution to orthogonalizing the variables or un-correlate them. **Will there be similar simple equations that we can use to perform the same trick in orthogonalizing $\chi^2$ or even non-centric $\chi^2$ variables?**

Comment: For simulating correlated $\chi^2(1)$ variates, why not just square a bivariate Normal distribution?

Comment: I can, however, I am interested in whether if there is any method that can simulate correlated $\chi^2(1)$ from independent $\chi^2(1)$ variables.

Comment: Sure: multiply the square roots of the $\chi^2(1)$ variates by independent Rademacher variables.  The result is a collection of *iid* standard Normal variates.  Use a linear combination of them to generate a multivariate Normal variable and square its components.  The relationship between the two covariance matrices is simple, but requires all correlations among the $\chi^2$ variates to be non-negative.

Comment: You might find this [related answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/306937/403940#403940) using the spectral decomposition to be of assistance.