# Quadratic form and Chi-squared distribution

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, eigenvalues, quadratic-form, chi-squared-distribution

It's about the demostration of the quadratic forms and chi-squared distribution.

Let's split the problem:

1. We have a $n$ vector with n standardized normal distribution called $z={[z_1,z_2...z_n]}$. 
   Obviously $z'z$ is a $\chi^2_n$
2. If we have a symmetric, idempotent matrix (i.e. called $A$) then $z'Az 
    \thicksim \chi^2_p $ where $p$ is the rank of $A$. I got this splitting the $A$ matrix with the spectral theorem into: $Q'\Lambda Q$ hence:
   $z'Az = z'Q'\Lambda Qz$ we call $w= Qz$ hence $z'Az =w'\Lambda w$. Because it's a idempotent matrix we have only 1s or 0s as eigenvalues and the number of 1's is exactly the rank of $A$. Then we have $w'w$ with with different length now as the number of the rank of $A$. We backward the process and we get: $z'Q'Qz$ but $Q'Q= I_{rank(A)}$ (they are orthogonal since we consider the eigenvectors) so we have the summation of $p$ $Z^2$.
3. Now the question comes: if we have a symmetric, positive definite matrix $\Sigma_{nxn}$ my teacher told me that $z'\Sigma z$ is a $\chi^2_n $ distribution. I was trying to find a proof, but I can't find one.
4. My efforts are: use the spectral theorem again, hence we have: $z'Q' \Lambda Qz$ but now $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with real positive numbers (cause it's positive definite).

   $\Lambda$= \begin{bmatrix}
       \lambda_{1} & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\
       0 & \lambda_{2} & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\
       \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
       0 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & \lambda_{n}
   \end{bmatrix}

We have called, as before, $w=Qz$ hence we have: $w'\Lambda w$. Let's suppose,  that w is 3-dimensional vector with 3 elements called a,b and c.
So $w=$ \begin{bmatrix}
    a  \\
    b \\
   c \\
 \end{bmatrix}

so $w'\Lambda w= a^2 \lambda_1+b^2 \lambda_2+c^2 \lambda_3$
And here I'm stuck.
Maybe this last point is wrong. Therefore I'm asking for clarification and a clear proof of what my teacher said.

**[EDIT]**

I found this:

*Let  $X$ be a $ K \times 1$ standard multivariate normal random vector, i.e.,  $X \thicksim N(0,I)$. Let  $A$ be an orthogonal  $K \times K$ real matrix. Define
$Y=AX$
Then also  $Y$ has a standard multivariate normal distribution, i.e., $Y \thicksim N(0,I)$.*
I'm okay with this, the proof is here: https://www.statlect.com/probability-distributions/normal-distribution-quadratic-forms
So my problem would come something like this: $w'\Lambda w$ where $w=QZ$ and by this theorem $w \thicksim N(0,I)$ since Q is an orthogonal matrix.
So, if w is a 3 dimensional vector I'll have something like this:

$\lambda_1 \chi^2_1 + \lambda_2 \chi^2_1 + \lambda_3 \chi^2_1 $ A lineare combination of chi-squared distribution with weights the value of the eigenvalues. Am I right? If I am, does this sum has a particular distribution?

Comment: Are you certain that in (3.), $z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I)$ and not $z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma^{-1})$? In which case clearly the quadratic is a $\chi^2$. Otherwise (for std. normal $z$ and symmetric PD $\Sigma$), I don't think $z'\Sigma z$ is distributed $\chi^2$: see answer (here)[https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9220/what-is-the-distribution-of-the-euclidean-distance-between-two-normally-distribut/10731#10731] for useful leads.

Comment: I added a new part, I don't know if it will be a notification. I'm new here and I'll be glad if you can read my edit to the post. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the wikipedia page for the [generalized $\chi^2$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution)

Comment: It has a chi-square distribution only under special conditions: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/188626/119261.

Comment: See also this:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442472/sum-of-squares-of-dependent-gaussian-random-variables/442916#442916

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### In general, the quadratic form is a weighted sum of $\chi_1^2$

It is not true in general that $\mathbf{z}^\text{T} \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{z} \sim \chi^2_p$ for any symmetric positive-definite (variance) matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}$.  Breaking this quadratic form down using the spectral theorem you get:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbf{z}^\text{T} \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{z} 
= \mathbf{z}^\text{T} \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{\Lambda} \mathbf{Q}^\text{T} \mathbf{z}
&= (\mathbf{Q}^\text{T} \mathbf{z})^\text{T} \mathbf{\Lambda} (\mathbf{Q}^\text{T} \mathbf{z}) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=1}^p \lambda_i ( \mathbf{q}_i \cdot \mathbf{z} )^2, \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

where $\mathbf{q}_1,...,\mathbf{q}_p$ are the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ (i.e., the columns of $\mathbf{Q}$).  Define the random variables $y_i = \mathbf{q}_i \cdot \mathbf{z}$.  Since $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is a real symmetric matrix, the eigenvectors $\mathbf{q}_1,...,\mathbf{q}_p$ are orthonormal, which  means that $y_1,...,y_p \sim \text{IID N}(0,1)$.  Thus, we have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbf{z}^\text{T} \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{z} 
&= \sum_{i=1}^p \lambda_i ( \mathbf{q}_i \cdot \mathbf{z} )^2 \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=1}^p \lambda_i \cdot y_i^2 \\[6pt]
&\sim \sum_{i=1}^p \lambda_i \cdot \chi_1^2. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

We can see that the distribution of the quadratic form is a weighted sum of $\chi_1^2$ random variables, where the weights are the eigenvalues of the variance matrix.  In the special case where these eigenvalues are all one we do indeed obtain $\mathbf{z}^\text{T} \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{z} \sim \chi_n^2$, but in general this result does not hold.  In fact, we can see that in general, the quadratic form is distributed as a weighted sum of chi-squared random variables each with one degree-of-freedom.

The general distribution for this form is complicated and its density function does not have a closed form representation.  [Davies (1980)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2346911) provides an algorithm to compute the distributions function (the algorithm is actually for a broader generalisation).  [Bodenham and Adams (2015)](https://spiral.imperial.ac.uk/bitstream/10044/1/23319/8/art_10.1007_s11222-015-9583-4.pdf) examine some approximations to this distribution, and provide comparisons with simulations.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! But, do we really need $\Sigma$ to be positive semi-definite for your proof? It seems to me that it's enough if it is symmetric. Then some $\lambda_i$ might be negative, but it still works. I did some calculations and it seems like allowing negative eigenvalues for $\Sigma$ works well! Thats not a proof, but I think your proof works with negative $\lambda_i$ as well. What do you think?

Comment: That is correct; if it is not positive semi-definite then you get at least one negative eigenvalue and the quadratic form has a non-zero probability of being negative.  However, in most statistical contexts you will encounter, the matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is a variance matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 3. above, suppose $\Sigma_{n\times n}$ is diagonal with diagonal elements $\{3, 2, 1\}$, then $\Sigma$ is symmetric positive definite. ...but $z'\Sigma z$ cannot be $\chi^2_n$ (chi-squared with 3 df), because $E\left[z'\Sigma z\right]=3E(z_1^2)+2E(z_2^2)+E(z_3^2)=6$, but the mean of a chi-squared with 3 df is 3.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Making use of the other answer here, for a diagonal matrix the eigenvalues are the diagonal entries, so in this case we would have $\mathbf{z}^\text{T} \boldsymbol{\Sigma} \mathbf{z} \sim 3 \cdot \chi_1^2 + 2 \cdot \chi_1^2 + 1 \cdot \chi_1^2$ (where each of those parts involve independent chi-squared-one random variables).